# How can i get id from url

Tags: php, url, get

How can i get this id from url? I want for all id's not only 1

http://szymciog.pl/stefan/gildia.php?gildia=1

i tried that:

```
$id_z_url = $_GET['id'] && $_GET['id']==''.$gildia['id'].'';
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: `$id_z_url = intval($_GET['gildia']) == 0 ? null : intval($_GET['gildia']);` set's the id to either `null` or something greater than `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$id_z_url = $_GET['gildia'];
```

With the name of the params, in your case `gildia`.

When you want to use `$id_z_url = $_GET['id'];` than you need to set the name `id` in the url like this: http://szymciog.pl/stefan/gildia.php?id=1

Comment: i added $id_z_url = $_GET['id']; but when i want to use that $id_z_url on echo i get blank panel:

Comment: You should get `1` when echo with this `$id_z_url = $_GET['gildia'];`

Comment: http://scr.hu/9a5/c9o2d
 thats my code, if i use this i get blank site: http://scr.hu/9a5/jt6cc

Comment: Where are you getting `$_GET['id']` from? because if you dont have a param in your url with the name `id` it gives you nothting. So your code doens't work...